# DRY out my Makefile: avoid duplicating Makefile recipes when commands differ by a single derivable parameter

Tags: templates, makefile

I am using a Makefile to generate templates from a set of parameter files. The parameter files are named `values-<something>.yml`, and the resulting templates are named `template-<something>-<network_mode>.yml`, where `<network_mode>` can be either `pod` or `bridge`.

The command to generate the two templates is identical with the exception of the network mode parameter (which can be derived from the target filename).

I was hoping I could write a rule like this:

```
%-template-bridge.yml %-template-pod.yml: values-%.yml
    NM=$@; NM=$${NM#*template-}; NM=$${NM%.yml}; \
    echo "something something network mode $$NM" > $@ || {rm -f $@; exit 1}
```

Unfortunately, while this works great when asking for individual files:

```
$ make cirros-template-bridge.yml
touch "cirros-template-bridge.yml"
$ make cirros-template-pod.yml
touch "cirros-template-pod.yml"
```

It doesn't work when asking for multiple files:

```
$ make cirros-template-bridge.yml cirros-template-pod.yml
touch "cirros-template-bridge.yml"
make: Nothing to be done for 'cirros-template-pod.yml'.
$ make cirros-template-bridge.yml cirros-template-pod.yml
make: 'cirros-template-bridge.yml' is up to date.
touch "cirros-template-pod.yml"
```

Note the first time it generate `cirros-template-bridge.yml`, but refused to generate `cirros-template-pod.yml` until it was invoked a second time. I assume this is because the syntax I'm trying to use means "the following recipe will generate both of these files", which isn't true.

What's the solution here?  I can obviously create two separate pattern rules, like this...

```
%-template-pod.yml: values-%.yml
    echo "something something network mode pod" > $@ || {rm -f $@; exit 1}

%-template-bridge.yml: values-%.yml
    echo "something something network mode bridge" > $@ || {rm -f $@; exit 1}
```

...but this means I need to keep the command line for the two recipes in sync. I really want something like a Make "subroutine". Is there a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had lots of these you could do something like create a `foreach` loop with `eval` etc. but since you just have two rules my opinion is that the simplest solution is to put the recipe into a variable and use it in both rules like this:

```
MAKE_TEMPLATE = NM=$@; NM=$${NM\#*template-}; NM=$${NM%.yml}; \
    echo "something something network mode $$NM" > $@ || { rm -f $@; exit 1; }

%-template-pod.yml: values-%.yml
        $(MAKE_TEMPLATE)
%-template-bridge.yml: values-%.yml
        $(MAKE_TEMPLATE)
```

Comment: I was thinking of something like that but I wasn't sure I could use per-target variables like `$<` in that case. Let me go try that out...

Comment: At least as written that results in errors (because everything after the `#` in `$${NM#...` is considered a comment.

Comment: I've edited your answer to avoid the errors. The above seems to work!

Comment: As long as you use `=` assignment then the right hand side is not expanded until it's in the recipe so all automatic variables are already set.

Comment: Another question: is the double-target pattern rule legal `make` functionality? I am quite surprised that it works at all, even more so as it seems to be treated like the newly introduced `&:` rules.

Comment: @vroomfondel yes, that's valid make syntax. See e.g. [the reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rules): "A rule appears in the makefile and says when and how to remake certain files, called the rule’s targets (most often only one per rule)." Explicit syntax [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax).

Comment: Pattern rules have always worked this way, since forever.  See the last paragraph in https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html and also see the examples in https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Examples.html